# Much older version of my Website shows when rebuilding Production Bundle with Webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, production-environment, pm2

I've noticed that when I rebuild my production bundle of my node.js app using webpack, the site in the browser reverts to a way older version (300+ git commits later). I use pm2 to run my website on my VPS.

How to keep the oldest version live until the new production build is done?

This is my webpack setup:

```js
    const { resolve } = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

    const cssOutputLocation = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
      'public/stylesheets/style-prod.css' :
      'stylesheets/style.css';

    const jsProdOutput = {
      filename: 'public/javascripts/build-prod.js',
      path: resolve(__dirname),
      publicPath: '/',
    };

    const jsDevOutput = {
      filename: 'javascripts/build.js',
      path: '/',
      publicPath: '/',
    };

    const jsOutputLocation = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? jsProdOutput : jsDevOutput;

    module.exports = {
      context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      entry: [
        './index.jsx',
      ],
      output: jsOutputLocation,
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|public\/)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'es2017'],
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|public\/)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'es2017'],
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: 'style-loader',
              use: 'css-loader',
            }),
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                },
                {
                  loader: 'sass-loader',
                },
              ],
              fallback: 'style-loader',
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin(cssOutputLocation),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, (context) => {
          if (!/\/moment\//.test(context.context)) { return; }
          // context needs to be modified in place
          Object.assign(context, {
            // include only CJK
            regExp: /^\.\/(nl|en-gb)/,
            // point to the locale data folder relative to moment's src/lib/locale
            request: '../../locale',
          });
        }),
      ],
    };

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      module.exports.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          screw_ie8: true,
          conditionals: true,
          unused: true,
          comparisons: true,
          sequences: true,
          dead_code: true,
          evaluate: true,
          if_return: true,
          join_vars: true,
        },
        output: {
          comments: false,
        },
      }));
      module.exports.plugins.push(new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin());
      module.exports.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin());
      module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(
          { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') },
        ),
      );
      module.exports.plugins.push(
        new CompressionPlugin({
          asset: '[path].gz[query]',
          algorithm: 'gzip',
          test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
          threshold: 10240,
          minRatio: 0.8,
        }),
      );
    }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      module.exports.entry.unshift(
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'react-hot-loader/babel',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      );
      module.exports.plugins.unshift(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hash` placeholder in the `filename` prop of your output config.

```
const jsProdOutput = {
  filename: 'public/javascripts/build-prod-[hash].js',
  path: resolve(__dirname),
  publicPath: '/',
};
```

With this your generated files will be unique on every build and will not be overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how does that explain that I'm seeing a version of 1 year ago, instead of the one that was there before the new build?

Comment: Because the whole pint of adding a hash to the generated file name is to avoid browsers using a cache version of the 1 year ago output file. One missing piece of my suggestion is that you have to point your `index.html` to load the right files (the one with the latest hash).

Comment: I'm not sure this is my problem. Because when I empty my cache, I still see that old version. Also, I don't need to remove the cache to see the updates on the new build even with my current webpack setup that is not using hashes in the bundle name.

Comment: If it's not a browser cache problem then be sure that right source code is getting build.